# how do I call a method of an ruby object by giving a string as the method name

Tags: ruby, methods

it's about Ruby.

I've got a Box Object with attributes such as "panel1", "panel2", ..., "panel5".
Instead of calling Box.panel1, Box.panel2, ... I want to call it like Box.method_call("panel" + some_integer.to_s).

I'm sure there is a way like this, but how's the correct way?

Yours,
Joern.

Comment: Have a look here http://www.khelll.com/blog/ruby/ruby-dynamic-method-calling/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given:

```
class Box
   def self.foo
      puts "foo called"
   end
   def self.bar(baz)
      puts "bar called with %s" % baz
   end
end
```

You could use **eval**:

```
eval("Box.%s" % 'foo')
eval("Box.%s('%s')" % ['bar', 'baz'])
```

Using **send** probably more preferred:

```
Box.send 'foo'
Box.send 'bar', 'baz'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I just tweaked it a little to add parameters.  Glad I could help.

Comment: Using send instead of eval is definitely the preferred way

Answer (score 5):

You're almost there. You just need to replace "method_call" with "send", which is how methods are actually called in Ruby - messages are sent to objects.

```
class Box
  def panel1
    puts 1
  end
  def panel2
    puts 2
  end
end

box = Box.new #=> #<Box:0x2e10634>
box.send("panel1")
1
panel = 2
box.send("panel#{panel}")
2
```